# Did Apple remove their Export Compliance advice?

Tags: app-store-connect

Up until a few months ago, when you uploaded a new build to iTunes Connect and tried to publish to TestFlight or the app store, Apple would display a simple yes-or-no dialog asking if your app uses cryptography. A few months ago, this dialog started containing a more detailed description of the export compliance guidelines, and some helpful advice about when you needed to select "yes" or "no" (I think it was something to the effect of "You can select 'no' if any of the following are true:" followed by a list of conditions).

Today when uploading a TestFlight build I am seeing the old dialog again - no detailed description or advice. Did Apple undo this change, or does it only show for app store builds?

(Please note I am not asking for advice on which option to choose; I already understand the export compliance process.)

Comment: I think I saw the detailed version when I submitted a new version of my app to the Store yesterday (oh and [shameless plug for my app](http://bit.ly/primecalc)).

Comment: This question is not off-topic. It is about iTunes Connect, which is *specifically listed* as an acceptable topic in the Site Tour.

Comment: +1 for not being at all development related, thus not off topic.

Comment: Reopened. Nevertheless the question could need some more editing to prevent answers from being primarily opinion-based. Why does it matter whether Apple undid this change or the message only shows for app store builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple undid this change, it would appear. There was no mention of the additional guidance being added and also no mention of it being removed, but it's definitely gone now.

I could speculate that due to the nature of changes to copy regarding legal features of iTunes Connect, that someone in the legal department decided that the change was unsuitable, but there's been no confirmation of anything to this effect.